How to get public channel list from Telegram?
I'm in the process of experimenting and learning the Telegram API and bot system.
Can anyone point me to a way to get a list of all public channels and member counts? I'm interested in all channels and not just the ones that I am a member of.
I do see some sites that list all channels which seem to be presenting themselves as directory services. Googling the question does not come up with much.
Does the Telegram API provide this information, or do I have to scrape this myself?
Thank you in advance.

That's not possible, Bot's can only see channels/groups they are member of. I'm willing to write a detailed answer but since this sound like an X/Y problem, please state what you're trying to achieve.

Any idea how these channel directory sites get their data if the apis don't exist? For example - https://tgstat.com/ratings/channels/crypto?sort=members

I've added it as an answer @rbourman!


Can anyone point me to a way to get a list of all public channels and member counts?

There is no Bot API route to get this information.
The only route that comes near is to use the getFullChannel method from the Telegram Core API. This will provide you with channel information and members, but your user must be a member of the channel.


Any idea how these channel directory sites get their data if the apis don't exist

They've probably made a custom Telegram client, for example using Telethon, which let there user join the Channel, and then use the mentioned method from above to scrape the channel info and member count, store that to a private database and show those results on the site you've linked.
Again, no automatic system, but custom using the Telegram Core API (MTProto).

So to give you an idea how to approach this using a MT Proto lib:

SearchGlobalRequest: Search for channels using (eg) some keyword:
Loop over the result of (1)
getFullChannel get information about channel
Write to a database


Using the Telegram Core API (MTProto) via Telethon has been my approach so far. Thank you.

Nice, hope my answer helps. Please let me know how I can improve it if needed.

At first, reference this.
TelegramChannels.me-- https://telegramchannels.me/
Telegram Group & Channel Listing-- https://telegram-list.com/
Telegram Directory-- https://www.telegramdirectory.me/

and also use search input:
 Type in keywords related to your interests, and 
 Telegram will display relevant public channels.
 You can also use the search filters to narrow down your 
 results by channel type, such as 'Groups', 'Channels', 
 etc.

Join Channel Catalog Channels:
 Some Telegram channels act as catalogs for other 
 channels. By joining these catalog channels, you can 
 discover new public channels that match your interests. 
 You can search for such catalog channels within 
 Telegram using the search feature.


tele bot api can't do this job. This api bot acts as a client generally, not as a server side.
unless the bot is there first, at the start of the channel. give him the task to
record in a special log like a spreadsheet who joined, what date, etc.

I'm not even sure what you are saying. What is a "special log?" I'm only looking for high level info about all the channels - name, id, number of members, and maybe country if it's available.

@rboarman I think OP is confusing the bot API and the client API. The bot API doesn’t have such endpoint, and from what I see neither does the client one.

Any idea how these channel directory sites get their data if the apis don't exist?
